# Can I optimize this XSL transform which takes records with unknown columns and turns it into a grid format?

Tags: xml, optimization, xslt

I'd like to optimize the XSL transform below. I've included sample input data and the sample output is creates. The input data is from a database with a **Record** element for each row, and child elements for each column that was selected. There could be any number of columns in any order with any name. I don't know any of that ahead of time (except for the **Id** element). I need to turn that data into a grid XML format that defines the columns used, then includes **row** elements for each record with **cell** elements for each column. The input data includes a **Columns** element whose child elements define the columns that need to appear in the output. I don't know what any of the columns might be ahead of time. All of the elements under **Columns** needs to appear in the output. The order of the columns/cells in the output is determined by the **order** attribute in the **Columns** child elements. The **Record** child elements that match the names of the **Columns** child elements supply the data for the corresponding **cell** element in the output. **Record** child elements that have no matching **Columns** child element are ignored. Not all **Columns** child elements will have corresponding **Record** child elements; for them we need to output an empty **cell** element.

Can I make this XSL work any better? I know that for-each is "bad". Can I template-ize this any more? Thanks!

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- The root element could have any name -->
<Data>
    <!-- There could be any number of Record elements -->
    <Record>
        <!-- Elements here may have any name and be in any order and may not be included in Columns -->
        <!-- For a particular XML file, all Record elements have the same child elements in the same order -->
        <Id>234542</Id>
        <Name>Tom Winter</Name>
        <SSN>XXX-XX-3317</SSN>
        <Facility>East Coast Hospital</Facility>
        <Status>AC</Status>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Id>345223</Id>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
        <SSN>XXX-XX-2344</SSN>
        <Facility>St. Joseph West</Facility>
        <Status>DE</Status>
    </Record>
    <Columns>
        <!-- There may be any number of element here and they can be in any order -->
        <Name label="Patient Name" display="yes" order="2"/>
        <MRN label="MRN #" display="yes" order="1"/>
        <BirthDate label="Birth Date" align="right" display="yes" order="3"/>
        <SSN label="SSN" display="yes" order="9" notSortable="yes"/>
        <DischargeDate label="Discharge Date" align="right" display="no" order="7"/>
        <Address label="Address" display="yes" order="8"/>
        <Facility label="Facility" display="yes" order="4"/>
    </Columns>
</Data>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:key name="recordId" match="Record" use="generate-id(.)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <grid name="exampleGrid">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Columns/*">
                <xsl:sort select="@order" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name(.)"/>
                <column label="{@label}" name="{$name}" align="{@align}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                <xsl:call-template name="Record"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </grid>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Record">
        <xsl:variable name="recordId" select="generate-id(.)"/>
        <row key="{Id}">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Columns/*">
                <xsl:sort select="@order" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="local-name(.)"/>
                <cell align="{@align}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('recordId', $recordId)/*[local-name(.) = $name]"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output:

```
<grid name="exampleGrid">
    <column label="MRN #" name="MRN" align="" />
    <column label="Patient Name" name="Name" align="" />
    <column label="Birth Date" name="BirthDate" align="right" />
    <column label="Facility" name="Facility" align="" />
    <column label="Discharge Date" name="DischargeDate" align="right" />
    <column label="Address" name="Address" align="" />
    <column label="SSN" name="SSN" align="" />
    <row key="234542">
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">Tom Winter</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align="">East Coast Hospital</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">XXX-XX-3317</cell>
    </row>
    <row key="345223">
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">John Doe</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align="">St. Joseph West</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">XXX-XX-2344</cell>
    </row>
</grid>
```

Comment: With your XSLT 1.0 processor, can you use an extension function like `exsl:node-set`? In that case I suggest to sort `//Columns/*` only once, store the result in a result tree fragment, convert that into a node-set with the extension function, all that done in global variables, and then use the variable with the sorted nodes instead of sorting again and again.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: +1 Good advice.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you know if this type of node-set function is available in MSXML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do this task:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vColumns" select="/*/Columns/*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <grid name="exampleGrid">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vColumns">
                <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
        </grid>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Columns/*">
        <column label="{@label}" name="{local-name()}" align="{@align}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <row key="{Id}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vColumns">
                <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
                <cell align="{@align}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                         select="$vCurrent/*[local-name()
                                              = local-name(current())]"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<grid name="exampleGrid">
    <column label="MRN #" name="MRN" align="" />
    <column label="Patient Name" name="Name" align="" />
    <column label="Birth Date" name="BirthDate" align="right" />
    <column label="Facility" name="Facility" align="" />
    <column label="Discharge Date" name="DischargeDate" align="right" />
    <column label="Address" name="Address" align="" />
    <column label="SSN" name="SSN" align="" />
    <row key="234542">
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">Tom Winter</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align="">East Coast Hospital</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">XXX-XX-3317</cell>
    </row>
    <row key="345223">
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">John Doe</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align="">St. Joseph West</cell>
        <cell align="right"></cell>
        <cell align=""></cell>
        <cell align="">XXX-XX-2344</cell>
    </row>
</grid>
```

With only one sort performed as suggested by Martin Honnen:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:variable name="vRTFColumns">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/Columns/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vColumns"
                  select="msxsl:node-set($vRTFColumns)/*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <grid name="exampleGrid">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vColumns">
                <column label="{@label}" 
                        name="{local-name()}" 
                        align="{@align}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
        </grid>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <row key="{Id}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vColumns">
                <cell align="{@align}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                         select="$vCurrent/*[local-name()
                                              = local-name(current())]"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: Adding an XSLT 2.0 solution because is the perfect example for `xsl:perform-sort` instruction.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vColumns" as="element()*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="/*/Columns/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <grid name="exampleGrid">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vColumns"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
        </grid>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Columns/*">
        <column label="{@label}" name="{local-name()}" align="{@align}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <row key="{Id}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$vColumns">
                <cell align="{@align}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                         select="$vCurrent/*[local-name()
                                             = local-name(current())]"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Nodes in `$vColumns` **sequence** retain their identity, and now we can use pattern matching with them.

Comment: Very nice. Don't know why I didn't put the actual record node in the variable instead of the id. Seems so obvious now!

Comment: @Tom Winter: You are welcome. @Flack: You also might be interested in the XSLT 2.0 solution from my last update.

Comment: A follow-up question since I don't XSL lingo super well. In the XSLT 1.0 example What would you call the contents of $vRTFColumns and $vColumns? I assume $vColumns contains a node-set.

Comment: May have answered my own question:

Is there somewhere I can find an example of the difference between a node set and a result tree fragment?
http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodeset.html

Comment: @Tom Winter: Yes, and $vRTFColumns holds a [Result Tree Fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments)

Comment: I implemented your second XSLT 1.0 solution and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom Winter: I'm glad it was useful. Ask any time.